# Access window.opener variables in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Okey I made it, it was actually pretty basic but somehow I didn't see it at first.
What I did is a module with my array and exported it:

```
export let openedWindows = []
```

Then import the module on the App.js:

```
import * as globalVars from './global';
```

And then in the `componentDidMount` method attach it to the window:

```
window.openedWindows = globalVars.openedWindows
```

That way when I open a new window I just push the window object to the array:

```
  handleAddWindow = (newWindow) => {
    window.openedWindows.push(newWindow)
  }
```

And I can close it or do whatever I want/can from another window/tab:

```
    handleCloseWindow = () => {
        window.opener.openedWindows[index].close()
        window.opener.openedWindows.splice(index,1) 
    }
```

Hope it helps to somebody :)

Comment: Are you saying that `window.opener` *isn't* available in the opened windows?

Comment: it is available, I've checked so doing `if (window.opener) {
        alert('Opend from another window')
      }`

Comment: What's the specific issue then?

Comment: I get `TypeError: Cannot read property 'openedWindows' of undefined`when I try this `window.opener.global.openedWindows[0].close()` So i don't know how to access the variable

Comment: If you've imported it as global, how are you attaching it to `window`? A module variable named `global` isn't *global*, it's in that module.

Comment: I know a name doesn't make it global, I attached it to the window with `window.openedWIndows = []` in the module, but I suspect I'm actually not attaching it properly to the window, so I want to know how to do it in order to access the opener vars

Comment: `window.openedWindows` != `window.global.openedWindows` (assuming the `openedWIndows` above is a typo).